# PHP page reload but script still executes

Tags: php, html

I am creating a php form for data validation but there are some errors that I can't find.
When I submit the form the required notification is displayed. But when I reload the page then the required notification still remains. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
// check if e-mail address is well-formed
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
}

if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
$website = "";
} else {
$website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
// check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0- 
9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
  $websiteErr = "Invalid URL";
}
}

if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
$comment = "";
} else {
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
$genderErr = "Gender is required";
} else {
$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
<br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> 
value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> 
value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> 
value="other">Other  
<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG6RB.png) when I first type the address in the browser.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgGmq.png) when I enter an empty value in all the fields and submit the form. This will remain when I reload the page and until I close the browser tab and open a new tab and enter the url again.

Comment: When you reload does it show you alert box?

Comment: @Vantiya yes it says about a confirmation and i pressed continue then nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got error message when you reload after form submission. Try following code into your JS file or in JS code.

```
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thank you a lot this works. do you please explain why this problem occur?

Comment: Let me help you understand that by your own. print_r the request when you submit the form first time. and reload the page after removing above script. Observe the output both the time. Repeat same process after adding above script. I'm sorry I'm not going to give you direct answer. I see your curiocity to know why the thing happens and I give you hint to explore it by yourself.

Comment: You also can saperate out the PHP code, JS code and HTML code. That is also a solution that you can't get form resubmitssion on page reload. In that you have to set page redirection from HTML page to PHP page and once you're done with DB entry again redirect from PHP file to HTML page.

Comment: thanks a lot. i learned an answer. when i refresh the page this replacestate function change the current url to browser address bar url. thats why i get the refresh window. but i can not understand why browser reload button not works??. i know i bother you already. if you have time then please leave an answere. thank you again. @Vantiya